# How to Solve Visual Studio C++ problem, "Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value."?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have marked the warning locations. If I understand correctly multiplying two 32-bit numbers can give 64 bits, so I am getting an error.

If C++ `int` is 32 bits then isn't storing 64 bits is also overflow? Please explain what I am doing wrong. The warning message is shown in Visual Studio 2019.

Casting to larger data type solves the problem. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


unsigned int m;
unsigned int n;


// Symbols 
int symbols[] = { -1, 0, 1 };
unsigned int symbols_size = sizeof(symbols) / sizeof(symbols[0]);



// Returns false to signify that element exiting in array
bool check_symbol_validity(int val) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < symbols_size; ++i) {
        if (symbols[i] == val) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{

    cout << "Place enter graph node count: ";
    cin >> m;
    n = m;


    // Just a separator
    cout << string(30, '#') << "\n";
    cout << "Enter Transition Symbol Between Node i and Node j. \nIf none then enter -1.\n";



    // Transition table, take node and symbol, return next node
    //int* transition_table = new int[m * symbols_size]; // WARNING
    int* transition_table = new int[(int64_t)m * symbols_size]; // OK


    // Declare C++ dynamic array
    //int* weight_matrix = new int[m * n]; // WARNING
    //int* weight_matrix = new int[(long)m * n]; // WARNING
    int* weight_matrix = new int[(long long)m * n]; // OK


    // Store positional values for direct access rather than using multiplication
    int* width_val_arr = new int[m];


    // TAKE VALID INPUT
    int user_input_value;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        int tmp1 = i * m;
        width_val_arr[i] = tmp1;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cout << "Enter connection between " << i << " and " << j << "\n";
            cin >> user_input_value;
            while (check_symbol_validity(user_input_value)) {
                cout << "WRONG! ENTER CORRECT VALUE." << "\n";
                cout << "Enter connection between " << i << " and " << j << "\n";
                cin >> user_input_value;
            }
            weight_matrix[tmp1 + j] = user_input_value;
        }
    }


    cout << string(30, '#') << "\n";


    // SHOW THE WEIGHT MATRIX
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        //int tmp1 = i * m;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << weight_matrix[width_val_arr[i] + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }



    // Delete the dynamic arrays
    delete[] weight_matrix;
    delete[] transition_table;
    delete[] width_val_arr;
}
```

WARNING MESSAGE:

> "Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow".

Comment: I do not understand what you are not understanding.  Where you marked the WARNING, you've also fixed the problem in the uncomment line.  A 32-bit times a 32-bit is 32-bit result.  A 64-bit times a 32-bit is a 64-bit result.

Comment: That does not look like an error.  It resembles C26450, a code analysis warning.  Hard to guess what rule is getting used, I certainly can't repro it from the given source.  Anyhoo, use Analyze > Configure to select which rules you want to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

> [C26451 RESULT_OF_ARITHMETIC_OPERATION_CAST_TO_LARGER_SIZE Using operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/C26451?view=msvc-160)
>
> Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator [operator] to avoid overflow
>
> This warning indicates incorrect behavior that results from integral promotion rules and types larger than those in which arithmetic is typically performed. We detect when a narrow type integral value was shifted left, multiplied, added, or subtracted and the result of that arithmetic operation was cast to a wider type value. If the operation overflowed the narrow type value, then data is lost. You can prevent this loss by casting the value to a wider type before the arithmetic operation.

[Arithmetic overflow checks in C++ Core Check](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/arithmetic-overflow-checks-in-c-core-check/)

Comment: That is the analysis rule I tested.  It didn't produce the diagnostic on the OP's code however.  Might be a VS version number issue, those rules are pretty new, tested with 16.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this warning because the compiler is assuming that since you are storing the result of the multiplication in a 64 bit wide type that you want to do the multiplication in 64 bit space as well.  When you do

```
m * symbols_size
// or
m * n
// or
(long)m * n
```

you are multiplying two 32 bit wide types together, so you get a 32 bit wide result. The size of an array though is a 64 bit wide type so it triggers the assumption.

As you can see you can silence this warning by making one of the operands 64 bits wide.  Another solution would be to just disable that warning if you do not care that you are doing the multiplication in 32 bit space.

Comment: @B200011011 You are using unsigned integer types so you calculate the result modulo 2^32.

Comment: Oops mistakenly deleted my previous comment. I am missing some fundamental understanding. But, as previous comment, If I multiply two 32 bit numbers, without sign bit 31 digits, 1111111111111111111111111111111 * 1111111111111111111111111111111 I get 11111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000001. How can it be stored in 32 bit wide result as given in the answer, "you are multiplying two 32 bit wide types together, so you get a 32 bit wide result".

Comment: @B200011011 Because in C++, that is how it works.  If they are signed integer types then you have signed integer overflow which is undefined behavior but most implementation use twos-compliment integers so the result would be 1 since you keep the least significant 32 bits of `11111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000001` which is `00000000000000000000000000000001`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and pretty much any other C-like high level languages) arithmetic operations between 2 numbers produces a value of the same type if the original types are the same, and a value of the *common type* of the two if they're different. Indeed multiplying two 32-bit numbers produces a 64-bit result but that's not how C++ works

> The arguments of the following arithmetic operators undergo implicit conversions for the purpose of obtaining the common real type, which is the type in which the calculation is performed:
>
> - binary arithmetic *, /, %, +, -
> - relational operators <, >, <=, >=, ==, !=
> - binary bitwise arithmetic &, ^, |,
> - the conditional operator ?:
>
> https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

The full rule to obtain the common type can be read in the link above, or in the standard below

If m and n are `int`s then their product is also an int. Hence there's a warning in `new int[m * n];` because the new operator receives a `size_t` which is a 64-bit unsigned type on your platform. Same to `new int[(long)m * n]` because the common type of `long` and `int` is `long` (which is also a 32-bit type on Windows)

**To get the full 64-bit product you need to cast at least one of the operands to a 64-bit type** which is `long long` in MSVC. That's why the last line `new int[(long long)m * n];` works. However you'll get a warning related to conversion between signed and unsigned

From [ISO/IEC 9899:201x C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)

> ## 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a *common real type* for the operands and result. For the specified operands, **each operand is converted, without change of type domain,** to a type whose corresponding real  type is the common real type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real  type is also the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the  type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is long double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is float.
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>     Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>     integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>     converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>     Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>     equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>     signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>     integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>     operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>     corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.